# XSLT Reformat XML Document

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking to make an XSLT that will transform the input XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <header>
        <from>From: exmaple@domain.com</from>
        <to>To: exmaple@domain.com</to>
    </header>

    <email>
        <body>Hello, email body here...</body>
    </email>

    <attachments>
        <attachment>
            <name>log1</name>
        </attachment>

        <attachment>
            <name>log2</name>
        </attachment>

    </attachments>
</payload>
```

into:

```
From: exmaple@domain.com
To: exmaple@domain.com

Hello, email body here...

To: exmaple@domain.com
log1


To: exmaple@domain.com
log2
```

Where the To node is repeated after every attachment. There can a number of attachments, not just two.

**UPDATE FROM USER**

Im pretty new to this, but i tried creating a payload without the header, email, and attachment tags. Then used  to arrange them into the correct order but this looks horrible. And is not scalable

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/         SO is not a place to come just to avoid doing any heavy lifting yourself.

Comment: Im pretty new to this, but i tried creating a payload without the `header`, `email`, and `attachment` tags. Then used `<xsl:value-of select="to"/>` to arrange them into the correct order but this looks horrible. And is not scalable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="from|to">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="attachments">
    <xsl:for-each select="attachment">
      <xsl:text>&#0010;&#0010;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../header/to"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
      <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```